# When you have multiple gold tag badges, how does the system decide which to use when closing as duplicate, and does it matter?

Tags: support, tags, closed-questions, duplicates

I have gold badges in [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) and [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells). My [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) gets used the most, however, just now I voted to close as duplicate a question with both tags, and the closure message listed [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells) as the gold tag badge I used:

[image]

Is there any rhyme or reason to how the system picks which tag to use when there are multiple available?

Bonus question, can this interfere with someone trying to reopen the question with a different tag badge? Could someone with just the [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) gold badge reopen this with a single vote?

Comment: At the very least, the system let me reopen it

Comment: Related, but ultimately unhelpful: "[With multiple gold tag badges, what determines which of them will be used as hammer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290712)"

Comment: @Medix2 Not just related, that’s exactly my question, but unfortunately it seems unresolved there.

Answer (score 5):

#### It probably doesn’t matter.

Medix2 was able to reopen the question with their [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) badge:

[image]

So it seems that as long as you have the gold badge for one of the tags, it doesn’t matter which tag badge is mentioned in the close message.

Answer (score 4):

#### It is loosely based on which tag badge is first created

According to [animuson on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371399/560258), it is loosely based on which tag badge was created first. Since (AFAIK) the [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells) tag has been around much longer, it probably got a tag badge first, meaning that it is probably the reason that the [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells) tag badge showed up when voting to close the question.

[animuson clarified in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290712/with-multiple-gold-tag-badges-what-determines-which-of-them-will-be-used-as-ham/371399#comment1239738_371399) that:

> It is not based on when the tags were created, but the tag badges
> themselves. Those are not created until the first person is eligible
> for the tag badge. Of note: the Badges table does not actually have a
> CreationDate column, so it's not technically based on date at all but
> just the order they were inserted into the table.

Comment: [The golden spells tag](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/199/spells) is actually newer than [the golden dnd-5e tag](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/138/dnd-5e) so I'm not sure this is true

Comment: @Exempt-Medic if I’m reading Animuson’s answer correctly, then it matter which one had any tag badge first, not which one had a gold tag badge first.

Comment: The answer states: "It should be loosely based on the order that the tag badge itself was first created and inserted into the database (we don't keep all three classes of every tag badge for every tag in the database - they just get inserted once someone first earns them)." I'm honestly unsure which interpretation is right, I'll go leave a comment. It does say the order the tag *badge* was made, hmmm

Comment: They've now responded more directly: "It is not based on when the tags were created, but the tag badges themselves." so maybe this is just an odd case where "loosely based on" really meant "loosely"